# Julia for loops slower than while?

Tags: julia

I'm playing around with the Julia language, and noticed that the small program I wrote was quite slow.
Suspecting that it was somehow related to the `for` loops, I rewrote it to use `while`, and got about 15x faster.

I'm sure there's something I'm doing wrong with the ranges etc., but I can't figure out what.

```
function primes_for()
    num_primes = 0
    for a = 2:3000000
        prime = true
  
        sa = floor(sqrt(a))
        
        for c in 2:sa
             if a % c == 0
                 prime = false
                 break
             end
         end

        if prime
            num_primes += 1
        end
    end
    println("Number of primes is $num_primes")
end

function primes()
    num_primes = 0
    a = 2
    while a < 3000000
        prime = true

        c = 2
        while c * c <= a
            if a % c == 0
                prime = false
                break
            end
            c += 1
        end
  
        if prime
            num_primes += 1
        end

        a += 1
    end
    println("Number of primes is $num_primes")
end

@time primes_for()
@time primes()
```

Comment: It's because `floor(sqrt(a))` returns a float rather than an integer, which slows down the divisibility testing you do. See [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/264270/project-euler-12-in-julia-slower-than-python/264347#264347) to almost the same question on Code Review.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in the comments by @Vincent Yu and @Kelly Bundy, this is because `sa = floor(sqrt(a))` creates a float. Then `c` becomes a float, and `a % c` is slow.

You can replace `floor(sqrt(a))` with `floor(Int, sqrt(a))`, or *preferably*, I think, with `isqrt(a)`, which returns

> Integer square root: the largest integer `m` such that `m*m <= n`.

This avoids the (unlikely) event that `floor(Int, sqrt(a))` may round down too far, which could happen if `sqrt(x^2) = x - ε` due to floating point errors.

**Edit:** Here's a benchmark to demonstrate (note the use of `isqrt`):

```
function primes_for2()
    num_primes = 0
    for a = 2:3000000
        prime = true
  
        # sa = floor(sqrt(a))
        sa = isqrt(a)
        
        for c in 2:sa
             if a % c == 0
                 prime = false
                 break
             end
         end

        if prime
            num_primes += 1
        end
    end
    println("Number of primes is $num_primes")
end

1.7.0> @time primes_for()
Number of primes is 216816
  6.705099 seconds (15 allocations: 480 bytes)

1.7.0> @time primes_for2()
Number of primes is 216816
  0.691304 seconds (15 allocations: 480 bytes)

1.7.0> @time primes()
Number of primes is 216816
  0.671784 seconds (15 allocations: 480 bytes)
```

I can note that each call to `isqrt` on my computer takes approximately 8ns, and that 3000000 times 8ns is 0.024 seconds. A call to regular `sqrt` is approximately 1ns.

Comment: Yes, seems `isqrt` is the proper way, I only kept using `sqrt` as that's what the other answer talks about.

Comment: Good that you noted that at the end, to rule out that it's not `sqrt` indeed being very slow.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I will play around with it a bit.
I hadn't realised that I got a float, but it makes sense when you think about it.
I seem to recall that you can annotate with types in Julia, so maybe if I explicitly declare `sa` as an integer, the compiler will do some magic and a % c will be faster?

Comment: No, that's not an idiomatic solution. Just use `isqrt`, that is the correct way.

Comment: Yup. Just changing `sa = floor(sqrt(a))` to `sa::Int32 = floot(sqrt(a))` will also make it as fast as the while-version.
Good to know.
I'm loving Julia more and more.
I have made a version of this little program in C, JS, C#, Smalltalk, Python, Rust and Pascal, and even though I didn't know Julia when I started, I think I only had to look up one or two thing. The rest, I just typed, and it worked.
But as the examples demonstrate, it's probably good to get some more experience with the language :-)

Comment: @DNF agreed. I just had to try it to see if the compiler would use it.
But 100% isqrt is clearer.

Comment: I wouldn't use type assertions for convertions. `isqrt` or `floor(Int, sqrt(a))`, or just `Int(sqrt(a))` are preferable.

Answer (score 5):

It's not the for/while that makes the speed difference, it's the `sqrt`.  It doesn't help that sqrt returns float, which promotes all the rest of the code around the sqrt output from integers.

Note that @time is not measuring the while and for loops, but also the code outside those loops.

If you are benchmarking code, the rest of your code needs to be the same, and removing the sqrt is one of the prime optimizations in this algorithm.  It's also possible to remove the `c * c` in the test, but this is trickier.

Comment: If I repeat the line with `sqrt`, the function doesn't get any slower. Why? Is that compiled away or so?

Comment: And if I change the `while` version to use `while c <= sa` (after computing `sa` the same way), it only gets factor 1.6 slower instead of factor 19 that the `for` version is slower. Please explain.

Comment: And if I use `sa = floor(Int, sqrt(a))` (as somewhat pointed out by Vincent), it's only about factor 1.02 slower. Your first paragraph seems to be simply wrong.

Comment: 1.02 difference is probably within the margin of error of the benchmark.  If changing sqrt makes it go from 15 times slower to 1.02 times slower, then I think it has proven my point.

Comment: No, if using sqrt instead of not using sqrt slows it down only 2%, that rather *disproves* your point.

Comment: It is unclear what code you are testing to get these results.

Comment: Their `while` version but with `sa = floor(Int, sqrt(a))` and `while c <= sa`.

Comment: So let me see if I understand.  You have two functions, one is 15x faster than the other, and you make a code change, and now they within the margin of error in speed difference, and you think that code change is NOT what made them different?

Comment: No, you misunderstand. I'm not talking about their `for` version.

Comment: I also find these descriptions kinda confusing, could you link to pastebin/gist snippets containing the actual code and the speeds you see for them?

Comment: @SundarR https://tio.run/##7VPLDsIgELzzFZtGk1Y9tPVqE69e/AVDK40opcoj@vd1QfuyB0/enISEnWVmAxPOVnCaPJqmtLIwvJZwVbxiOgkjAghpq8OLgQxiT1HcpX53P3HBsN7AOvbwrIOX4DmjLCMdW3TKXl3AAtcmA9o1HHiJvnOnaMcO0dqXVGg26eaK0cuIZfI4qgtYZpCQcZsMZvsBI8ngISbarqB9rx2JGmmEDIO9rXKmoH6ba@AaZr1rEBFv9ZFD@osctJOWoq5VuJNmBfqmTEij6EtQGJL@p@SttsZdrf8qwxoja5on